# I arrange an chart but In present, i can't see chart

Tags: user-interface, mobile, figma

I'm making mobile game UI using '**Figma**'.

I have some problems with Present.

When I arrange an chart but In present, i can't see chart.

I'm trying to solve it by myself, but its so difficult.

**On figma contains:**
[image]

**On prensent contains:**
[image]

Comment: That chart is not placed inside your artboard, but above it. You can solve this by copy the chart, select the artboard then paste it — the chart should now be placed in the middle of the artboard. (You could also just drag it out and place it back in, but i find it unreliable)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to programming, maybe it should be asked on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ instead